# Http 404 error when uing Gitlab API to add SSH key

Tags: python, gitlab, ssh-keys

I have a valid user_id, and also the admin token (which is stored in GITLAB_ADMIN_TOKEN)

But when I run following Python to add the SSH key for user id, I get a 404 error.

```
# Add SSH Key
url = 'http://114.xx.xx.xx:8080/api/v3/users/' + str(user_id)+ '/keys?private_token=' + GITLAB_ADMIN_TOKEN
print url
values = {'id':user_id,
      'title':'mykey',
      'key':'ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ..... root@ubuntu'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

The result is:
   http://114.xx.xx.xx:8080/api/v3/users/30/keys?private_token=xxxxxx

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testgitlab.py", line 61, in 
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 2):

I know where is the problem now. 
In my original implementation, I pasted the key with

`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCrTAR1MVs1juu1MuZ8C09CZpxm56hDzguRGuenmHez7Co9NQyx3GKLa5ksfdMNk+OBLVuf/fFZZ1ZoFGH9Cz/xNkxwtzjd6UiTt/6ECO9rClYK3LfX5RTv7a2O9zxhsudpofhIkUS0fYFmRlTi/htssbU5IC+U1i+xXHvfBChdLd2EasakGB89+Sw5t74cVyMiC8mRkcLxpCRI1BPEQd5FRZQr8piQxW2APcWnT7h18gY1F9qm50pq2PQgk7rQtkLMQKVVu30/95W7IBVfTMfklnDk3z0Dj4EcqzKYeeenwVn6YdC3fI5ZmLTpNhLlLwJPlBDQnUSIn8pBrmXfpPy7 root@ubuntu`

But the `root@ubuntu` shouldn't be included. When I removed it from my `2048-bit` key, it works now.